# Existence of measure under inverse transformation

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose there is nonempty compact metric spaces $X$, $Y$ and a continuous surjective transformation $T : X \to Y$. For given finite measure $\nu$ on $(Y,\mathcal{B})$, is a measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{B})$ with the property that for any continuous $f : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ $$\int_{Y} f d\nu = \int_{X} f \circ T d\mu $$ uniquely exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

This is a more general change of variables formula, compared to the usual change of variables proved for diffeomorphisms (however, the ladder is much more difficult to actually prove compared to the general case, for one must prove that the push-forward measure actually is equal to the Jacobian of the diffeomorphism times the original Lebesgue measure).